# Toggle Boolean on UITableView Selected Row

Tags: ios, uitableview, boolean

I'm trying to toggle a Boolean value when a table row is selected.  This code was working when my table rows contained NSObjects (in a different class)...I simplified my code so that the rows only contain strings and not objects (cut out the class), but now the boolean won't toggle because my instance variable is a string.  Here's the original working code:

Declared in XYZObject:

```
@property BOOL checked;
```

Table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
XYZObject *tappedItem = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tappedItem.checked = !tappedItem.checked;
NSString *addedItem = cell.textLabel.text;
if(!tappedItem.checked) {
    [newArray removeObject:addedItem];
} else {
    [newArray addObject:addedItem];
}
```

When I change XYZObject to NSString and move the Bool property to the table view, I get the "Property 'checked' not found on object of type 'NSString *'.  Changing NSString to NSObject does the same thing.  If I change NSString to XYZMyTableViewController, it will now compile but then breaks at runtime due to "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

So my question would be, can I toggle the 'checked' Bool value on an array of strings?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

I was able to solve the problem by eliminating the Bool entirely and just using:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [newArray addObject:addedItem];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [newArray removeObject:addedItem];
}
```

I'm not particularly happy as I had some other methods using 'checked', but I should be able to just rewrite them in the same way.  I'd still like to know why I wasn't able to toggle a bool value on a string that's in my table cell.

Comment: You moved the boolean instance variable to the tableview?  If that's the case, that's the reason the property is not being found-you are asking to change a property or instance variable that doesn't exist(for the NSString object).  You would need to set it like myTableView.checked = !myTableView.checked

Comment: Yeah, since I completely ditched XYZObject I moved the BOOL checked from that into my table view.  I'm a bit confused on changing a variable that doesn't exist, I'm still declaring *tappedItem as an NSString (I've also tried declaring it in the interface as well).  What do you mean when you say that variable doesn't exist?

Comment: I simply changed XYZObject to XYZTableViewController, now everything compiles but hits a breakpoint when tappedItem.checked is called for "NSCFString checked: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Unless you subclass NSString(which I'm fairly certain you cannot do), you cannot declare a property or instance variable that doesn't already exist.  You can declare whatever property or instance variable for your own classes, but not for classes from the API, unless you subclass them(like XYZTableViewController). The error message means you called a method that hasn't been implemented